# Viewing all data in Pug, from MongoDB with express issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have the following Pug file:

```
extends layout

block content   .main.container
    .row
      .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        h1.display-4.m-b-2 All Current Projects
        p Projects
         ul
         each project in project
          li #{title}
```

And the following GET request:

```
// GET /projects
router.get('/projects', mid.requiresLogin, function (req, res) {   
  project.find({}), function (err, docs) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else return res.render('project', { title: project.title });
  });
});
```

I cannot seem to get the project's details to display via my pug template. I have tried many things, but it's clear I must be doing something simple wrong. I'm currently recieving the error of `"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` but both project and title are defined, both with the exported projects model below:

```
const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required:[true, "Title is required"],
  },
});
```

If anyone can help, I would be very appreciative. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
router.get('/projects', mid.requiresLogin, function (req, res) {   
  project.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else return res.render('project', { title: docs.title });
  })
});
```

Notice your bracket were not well closed at `project.find({}),` and the `project.tittle` should be `docs.tittle`